# Getting OAuth2 authentication to use instagram tag search API

Tags: api, tags, instagram, instagram-api

I want to use instagram's `API` but it asks me for authentication. I have logged in instagram but still I cannot get the authentication. Going through the web I found that we need to `Register a new client` but I don't know what details I need to give there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is certainly not a comprehensive answer, but to get you started go to https://www.instagram.com/developer/register/ and look for the Manage Clients button in the upper right corner. You'll need to be logged in first. Then click Register Your Application. You will have to have your callback URL ready to go, what they call the `redirect_uri`.

Comment: I have registered client and got the token. But I can use the access token just for unauthorized access like instagram's tag search using 
`https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/search?q=snowy&access_token=637413668.18a93ee.f140b73c9d304a0693012a915c6a7561`. 

But I want to use insta's media search by providing certain tag names but  `apegee` asks for `oauth2` authentication and it says that I am not a sandbox user.